# Using startsWith as a custom Pipe

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Actually I want to Use `*ngIf` checking if a string starts with certain character.

Is it possible to do this by using angular? I have tried but I got error

**HTML**

```
<app-breadcrumb  *ngIf="startsWith:url === '/register/'"></app-breadcrumb>
```

**Component**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'startsWith'
})
export class UserComponent implements PipeTransform {
  transform(fullText: string, textMatch: string): boolean {
    return fullText.startsWith(textMatch);
  }
}
```

Comment: why not use `*ngIf="url.indexOf('/register')==0"`? or use a function, not a Pipe?

Comment: it working!!. Can you add in answer..So I can upvote you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding to what Eliseo has to say, I would also like to correct your existing use of `pipe`.

```
<div>{{ name | startsWith : 'Ang' }}</div>

<div *ngIf="( name | startsWith : 'Ang')"> Can see </div>

<div *ngIf="( name | startsWith : 'Test')"> Can't see </div>
```

Take a look at this demo [code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-pipe-example-fwkhap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**OR**

```
<app-breadcrumb  *ngIf="(url.startsWith('/register/'))"></app-breadcrumb>
```

Don't use `pipe` for such checks, its mostly for data transformation

Answer (score 2):

A pipe is meant to transform the the input. As angular documentation states

> A pipe takes in data as input and transforms it to a desired output.

You may simply use

```js
<app-breadcrumb  *ngIf="url.startsWith('register')"></app-breadcrumb>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it used in a pure way like this? Or is it constantly calling this code because it doesn't recognize the purity of the function?